# How can we find the jdk path in the system drives(like C,D etc) using java program?

Tags: java

Hi can anyone tell me "**How can we find the jdk path in the system drives(like C,D etc) which is currently used by user using java program?**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query [`System.getProperties()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29):

- `java.home` : Java installation directory
- `java.class.path` : Java class path
- `java.library.path` : List of paths to search when loading libraries